# Save quantmod::getSymbols output to csv file and then read csv as a xts object

Tags: r, xts, quantmod

What the easy way to save download stock symbol data (by quantmod) in csv file and read with original xts format?

```r
getSymbols("000001.SZ", from = "1990-10-01", auto.assign = TRUE)
write.csv(`000001.SZ`, "000001_yahoo.csv")
my_zoo <- read.csv("000001_yahoo.csv")
```

But the data will not be in a xts format.

And I get an error if I use `read.zoo()` to change the `read.csv` result.

```r
my_zoo <- read.csv("000001_yahoo.csv")
PAYH <- read.zoo(my_zoo, format = "%Y-%m-%d", sep = ",",
                 header = TRUE, index.column = "Date")

## Error in read.zoo(my_zoo, format = "%Y-%m-%d", sep = ",", header = TRUE,  : 
##   index has 8106 bad entries at data rows: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14
##  15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39
## 40 41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48 49 50 51 52 53 54 55 56 57 58 59 60 61 62 63 64
##  65 66 67 68 69 70 71 72 73 74 75 76 77 78 79 80 81 82 83 84 85 86 87 88 89
## 90 91 92 93 94 95 96 97 98 99 100 ..
```

What's the function to easy save and load xts data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that it is important that the file be in csv format use `write.zoo` and `read.csv.zoo` like this.  Note that `getSymbols` adds some xts attributes that are not needed so zap them to ensure that the original object and the read-in object are identical.

```
library(quantmod) # also loads xts and zoo
getSymbols("000001.SZ", from = "1990-10-01")
xtsAttributes(`000001.SZ`) <- NULL

write.zoo(`000001.SZ`, "000001_yahoo.csv", sep = ",")

z <- read.csv.zoo("000001_yahoo.csv", check.names = FALSE)
x <- as.xts(z)

identical(`000001.SZ`, x)
## [1] TRUE
```

Comment: How about the this below code to save as a rds flie, it looks keep the original formate ?
```r
saveRDS(`000001.SZ`, file = "000001_yahoo.rds")

PAYH<- readRDS("000001_yahoo.rds")
```

Comment: The question asks for csv.